# Need clarification regarding gets function in C

Tags: c, gets

I am new to C programming.  I am trying to practice a simple exercise problem:  It is the following:

*Write a program that reads input lines one by one until the end of file is reached, determines the length of each input line, and then prints only the longest line that was found.  You may assume the maximum input line length is 1000 characters.*

My code is pasted here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 1000

int main(void)
{
    char line[MAX_LEN], line_temp[MAX_LEN];
    int largest_line_size = 0;
    int current_line_size;

    while ( gets ( line_temp ) != NULL)
    {
        if ( ( current_line_size = strlen( line_temp ) ) > largest_line_size )
        {
            strcpy(line, line_temp);
            largest_line_size = current_line_size;
        }

        /*printf("%s\n", line); */
    }
    printf("%d", largest_line_size);
    printf("%s", line);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

The problem is that the code runs, accepts input, but I never get to a point where the while loop breaks.  How do I encounters a NULL pointer when using gets() function?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: _Until the end of the file is reached..._ not sure you are doing the right thing, IMO?!

Comment: The questions says until the end of file is reached.  It doesn't mean it is reading from a file, it could very well be stdin.  In any case, how do I check if no more input is provided by the user through stdin stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem myself.  The way you get to terminate the loop in the above code when reading characters from stdin is by pressing CTRL-D (Unix) or CTRL-Z in Windows.  In either cases, an EOF is triggered and the gets or fgets command returns a NULL pointer.  Sorry for wasting time, if that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question says **You must read the input from a file**.
Why are you accepting it at run time from the user?

For example, if `fr` is a file, you can do the following.

```
fr = fopen ("filename", "rt");  /* open the file for reading */
/* filename is the name of the file */
/* "rt" means open the file for reading text */

while(fgets(line_temp,MAX_LEN, fr) != NULL)
{ //...do your stuff }
```

**Note that `fgets()` returns NULL when there are no more lines in the file.**

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: well, i am at a chapter in C the book that I am following, where reading/writing to a file is not discussed.  Although the question says end of file, it does not mean the inputs are read from a file.  it could very well be from stdin.  How can you get a NULL pointer when reading characters from stdin?  what inputs/key strokes do you need to provide at the stdin?

Comment: @user3317287 NULL == '\0' == eof